# Homework on bubble sorting efficiently

Tags: python, sorting, bubble-sort

I'm trying to do bubble sorting in an efficient manner. I have a count which adds up all the call I've made to the function `bubble`. I need to find a way to make it efficient where if the `bubble` function is called and no values in the list are swapped, then i shouldn't call the bubble function again.

I have this code with three functions here

```
def bubble_sort(values):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(values)-1):
        count += 1
        bubble(values)
    return count

def bubble(values):
    while True:
        swapped = False
        for i in range(len(values) - 1):
            if values[i] > values[i + 1]:
                swap(values, i, i+1)
                swapped = True
        if not swapped:
            break

def swap(values, i, j):
    values[i], values[j] = values[j], values[i]

test_1 = [1, 3, 67, 58, 91, 36, 100, 28, 90, 10, 57, 51, 52, 64, 56]
x = bubble_sort(test_1)
print(x, test_1)

test_2 = [2, 3, 4, 1, 5, 6, 7]
y = bubble_sort(test_2)
print(y, test_2)
```

when I try run the following code the output I get is:

```
14 [1, 3, 10, 28, 36, 51, 52, 56, 57, 58, 64, 67, 90, 91, 100]
```

the expected output is:

```
8 [1, 3, 10, 28, 36, 51, 52, 56, 57, 58, 64, 67, 90, 91, 100]
```

I thought that editing my bubble code would do the trick, but it doesn't change anything even if I were to use a normal bubble-sort function.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Here is the good explanation and solution: https://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/SortSearch/TheBubbleSort.html you can take a look at particularly to `shortBubbleSort` function but I would suggest going through all would be more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to break out the outer loop in `bubble_sort` that is calling `bubble` in case there's no swaps. Just remove `while` from `bubble` and return a bool indicating if swaps were made. Then you can stop the `for` loop in `bubble_sort` if you get `False` as return value:

```
def bubble_sort(values):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(values)-1):
        count += 1
        if not bubble(values):
            break
    return count

def bubble(values):
    swapped = False
    for i in range(len(values) - 1):
        if values[i] > values[i + 1]:
            swap(values, i, i+1)
            swapped = True

    return swapped
```

With these modification you get the expected output:

```
(8, [1, 3, 10, 28, 36, 51, 52, 56, 57, 58, 64, 67, 90, 91, 100])
(4, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
```

Answer (score 1):

Efficient bubble sort. Hah.

A simple fix would be to just have your `bubble` function return `False` if it doesn't perform any swaps.

```
def bubble(values):
    has_changed = False
    while True:
        swapped = False
        for i in range(len(values) - 1):
            if values[i] > values[i + 1]:
                swap(values, i, i+1)
                has_changed = True
                swapped = True
        if not swapped:
            break
    return has_changed
```

Then, in your `bubble_sort` function:

```
def bubble_sort(values):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(values)-1):
        count += 1
        has_changed = bubble(values)
        if has_changed == False:
            break
    return count
```

Comment: I know that bubble sorting is O(n^2).This is not very efficient so maybe saying efficient was a stretch. Thank for the help.